# How to publish only onCommit events from entities?

Tags: database, spring, jpa, entitylisteners

I'm using jpa `EntityListners` annotation to listen event for whenever an entity is updated. Problem is annotations `@PostPersist` and `@PostUpdate`trigger this event on both `commit` and `flush`. And in my code, im using flush before committing (can't change this logic/can't remove flush call). Example of my code:

```
@Transactional
public void updateValue(int id, String value) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            BusinessEntity bEntity = businessRepository.findById(id);
            bEntity.setValue(value);
            businessRepository.merge(trip);

            //First event is fired
            businessRepository.flush();


            someService.performLogicThatUpdatesBusinessEntityAgain();

        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
//transaction is committed and hence Second event is fired
}
```

This causes the two events to be fired too close to each other. Both with different values of entity. Which happens in a large volume messes the sequence of events. The entity listener also publishes the event to a queue. And a consumer reads the dto of the entity and saves/updates in a no-sql. Can I avoid the flush event? **So that I only get the entity updated per transaction**?

Answer (score 0):

According to the JPA specification, `@PostPersist` and `@PostUpdate` callbacks occur after the database insert/update operations. This implies that they will be executed after each 'relevant' flush (in your case, after the explicit flush after the `merge` call and the implicit one when transaction commits).

Are you sure it is impossible to change the logic to avoid the explicit flush? In the code that you've shown, the merged entity already has an id, do you need any other side effects?

There really doesn't seem to be a workaround, but perhaps you could use some conditional logic in your event handler based on the state of the entity that is changed after the explicit flush?